# Raycast + Align Euler to Vector. Wrong Hit Normals

Tags: geometry-nodes

I try user Raycast with "Align Euler to Vector" node.
Target is simple rotate plane (4 vertex).

As a result, some triangles are rotated incorrectly. What's wrong ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's how your setup is evaluated:

[image]

1. White line ⬅ *Group Output* decides to evaluate the *Geometry*
2. Cyan lines ⬅ *Instance on Points* decides to evaluate *Points*, and evaluated data returns on yellow lines ➡. Nodes (1) - (4) were evaluated.
3. Pink line ⬅ *Instance on Points* decides to evaluate *Instance*, and evaluated geometry returns on the green line ➡. Node (5) was evaluated.
4. Red lines ⬅ *Instance on Points* decides to evaluate *Rotation* for each instance, and evaluated vectors return on the blue lines ➡. Nodes (6) - (8) were evaluated.
5. *Instance on Points* finishes work, returning the data to *Group Output* on the black line ➡. Nodes (9) & (10) were evaluated.

I tried to make it clear *Object Info* and *Raycast* nodes are evaluated two times each. So if you duplicated those nodes, I think the execution would be exactly the same (maybe some optimizations wouldn't kick in, but other than the evaluation time, the result would be the same):

[image]

While the *Object Info* node might have some cache, because it returns the same data the second time, the latter, the *Raycast*, is given different *Source Position* - the 2nd time it's the position of the instance, which is already positioned on the plane.

So it is now up to the quirkiness of the floating point calculations if a ray shot from the plane down will hit the plane or not. With node wrangler enabled, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>clicking the *Instance on Points* node (the context) and the *Raycast* node (to read values for this context) will reveal *Is Hit* for many instances (those with wrong rotations) is ❌ False.

The simplest fix is to edit *Plane.001*, duplicate the plane and move it down. Now there's a second plane with the same normal to be sampled by (7) node.

The proper fix is to use a *Capture Attribute* node, to remember the *Hit Normal* to not have to run the node again (it will therefore also reduce the evaluation time of the setup):

[image]

---

More reading:

- [Combine two position nodes from different mesh primitives inside a geometry node tree](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/251310/60486)
- [Geometry Nodes: What Does Capture Attribute Add to Geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292029/60486)
- [Understanding how "vertex of corner" works in geometry node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292389/60486)
- [Passing Data Into Simulation Zone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/296223/60486)