# Geometry Nodes: how do I transfer vertex IDs?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to set the vertex IDs of a specific vertex group.

First, to set the IDs of the vertex group, I separate the group and convert to a curve and back, in order to make sure the vertices are in order, then I give them IDs:
[image]

However, when I try to transfer the vertex IDs over to the main mesh, the IDs don't carry over and the Capture Attribute mesh doesn't seem to work:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: There are two 'curve to mesh' nodes connected serially. In the first image, it even shows the error. Idk why it didn't show up in the second one. But that can be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access an anonymous attribute on the geometry that doesn't have this attribute.

You can read more here: [What Does Capture Attribute Add to Geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292029/60486)

In order to access the right geometry, you could sample the nearest vertex of that geometry:

[image]

Keep in mind the ID is the *Index* by default, so you can simplify this setup:

[image]

Comment: So I copied your setup and it appears to work. I will look into it in more detail. Thank you!