# Add object on position of face

Tags: geometry-nodes, faces

Can someone explain me why my node tree is failing?
I want to spawn Geometry on faces that I delete.

Here two half hexagon faces are deleted (if they where thre you would see 3 hexagons...):

[image]

Here is the network:

[image]

Here is the output of the viewer node, notice that x 0.433 and x 1.299 are correct.

[image]

Yet the boxes spawn at 0,0,0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You connect your *Viewer* node to one geometry, where the captured attribute exists. If you connected it to the "Cube" geometry, you would also see zeroes in the spreadsheet. For the most part, there's no errors in geonodes, so if you e.g. access an attribute on geometry that doesn't have one, instead of having an error of some kind, you just get the value $0$.

Here's the setup you want to use instead:

[image]

And here's an equivalent setup closer to your logic:

[image]

More reading:

[What Does Capture Attribute Add to Geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292029/60486)