# setting position of each instance with captured attribute node to each vertex

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a `cube` and `cone` , and I want to place each cone in the corner of the cube.
The simple way to do it would be:

[image]

But, I'm trying to understand how capture attribute works, so I'm trying to set the position for these instances explicitly by using the positions that I capture from the geometry(cube). I did something like this:

[image]

It seems to superimpose all 6 instances into the median of the cube. I suppose it's a bit unreasonable for me to expect it would match the number of instance for each vertex position.

Then does that mean the value of the captured attribute is the median of all the position of vertices? Then again, I also do know that it can be actually use to get face/vertex specific data like this:
[image]

So I'm confused, How does the capture attribute actually work? Does it give an average of all set of data in the spreadsheet? And how can I use this to set the position of the given set of instances to the position of each vertex?

Comment: In your second image, geometry output of the capture attribute is linked to nothing. In consequence its output is always (0,0,0). This output should be connected among so that there is a defined context to capture into.

Comment: @lemon , but where do I actually connect it to?

Comment: [What Does Capture Attribute Add to Geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292029/60486)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capture attribute node output should be connected to a (chain of) element(s) in order to be used by them.

[image]

Think about it like so:

In the cube geometry flow,

We capture (capture is known at cube vertex/point level)

This capture is linked to "instance on points" (capture is known at instance level)

This is linked to "set position" (capture is know of it as we are talking about instance position, which know the capture)

etc.

[Read more about capture attribute node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292029/60486)

Comment: I somehow get an intuition for it, but, using the same method how would you put a cone on each face of the cube? I tried changing the domain to face which didn't quite work ( thought it should have gotten the position of each face which should had been 6 points, but cones don't appear accordingly) https://ctrl.vi/i/BGqTc5iFf

Comment: Well, 8 points, 6 faces... so not directly. Use "mesh to point" with "face" option.