# Visualizing the "Selection socket" of the "Set Position" node

Tags: geometry-nodes

Could someone please correct me if I am wrong?

It takes Boolean. So If I connect only the **Z** axis via *"Separate XYZ"* and use *"Compare Node"* to get only values larger than 0 it will look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Set Position* node iterates over instances and points (vertices, curve control points, point cloud points) of the supplied *Geometry*, and for each:

1. Evaluates the *Selection* field, which by default is *True*. If the field is evaluated to *True*, the point will be moved, otherwise it's left alone.
2. Evaluates the *Position* field, which by default is using the *Position* node. The evaluated position is where the point will be moved.
3. Evaluates an additional *Offset* field, which by default is $<0, 0, 0>$, this vector is added to the position, that is, the two below frames are equivalent:

[image]

So it's pretty simple, a point is either moved or not, it doesn't treat each axis separately. So, based on the implicit conversion rules I described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/267158/60486), value $0$ becomes *False*, and value $1$ becomes *True*. Therefore using a field, that for first 5 points evaluates to $1 = $ *True*, and for the latter 5 points evaluates to $0 = $ *False*, makes it so only the first 5 points are moved, and the latter 5 points aren't.

More reading:

- [Combine two position nodes from different mesh primitives inside a geometry node tree](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/251310/60486)
- [Raycast + Align Euler to Vector. Wrong Hit Normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/253612/60486)
- [Geometry Nodes: What Does Capture Attribute Add to Geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292029/60486)
- [Understanding how "vertex of corner" works in geometry node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292389/60486)
- [Passing Data Into Simulation Zone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/296223/60486)

Comment: Thank you very much Markus ❤️❤️❤️ you helped me a lot today. I hope one day I will be able to provide answers for other people too. I am very ambitious with very little knowledge. I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet but as soon as I reach 15 points I will do it. Thanks again. 